# Cut off text in comments section

Tags: bug, status-completed

I'm seeing the below when viewing [this question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/24523/why-is-the-lowest-iso-always-100).

The text says "Avoid comments like" and then doesn't suggest what comments to avoid. I suggest that either examples are added or the text removed.

[image: cutoff]

Comment: I see that too, even typing this comment it had that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should see this fixed in the next build (i.e after 2013.07.25.892), as this is [now fixed and will be deployed "soon"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/190351/130044)